RPi camera v3 IMX 708 12MP doesn't focus
I have a V3 IMX708 12MP in a RPi 4 w/Bookworm installed in a box for doing remote photos.
It doesn't have a screen attached, it is managed via ssh and the photos are uploaded to a cloud.
Before letting the camera in its final position I made a couple of tests and the results were good.
But now all photos are out of focus, it seems the lens has a bad fixed position I cannot realize how to correct it.
This is a simplified  version of the script I am using:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import os, libcamera, subprocess, sys
from libcamera import controls
picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_still_configuration({"size":(4608,2592)})
picam2.configure(camera_config)
picam2.set_controls({"AfMetering": controls.AfMeteringEnum.Auto})
picam2.set_controls({"AfMode": controls.AfModeEnum.Auto})
picam2.start()
#
sleep(2)
picam2.capture_file(filename)
picam2.close()

I tried changes like
picam2.set_controls({"AfMode": controls.AfModeEnum.Manual, "LensPosition": 0.5})
or
picam2.set_controls, {"AfMode": 0 ,"LensPosition": 0.5}
Also tried from shell rpicam-still --autofocus-mode=manual --lens-position=0.5 -o photo1.jpg
Update 1:
The camera, the RPi4, relay, servos and controller are inside a box. The lens is behind a photographic UV glass.
I found that positioning the vertical servo servo_V_def = 100 the focus is correct but with servo_V_def = 110 (lower angle) focus is bad in the entire picture.


UV filter could not be the best quality but there's much differences between those pics.
Update 2:
Definitively it is not a UV glass issue.
I moved the camera vertically (near the horizon) servo_V_def = 90 and the picture was in focus, then I lower the camera to servo_V_def = 100 (where the test picture was good) and I got an out of focus photo.
I really don't get it.  Could it be a problem between relay (only on 2 seconds to position the servos) and the camera? (!!)

made a couple of tests and the results were good ... do the tests again

I had such a bad experience with Pi cameras several years ago, I swore off them forever... hope your luck is better. In my case the problem was that the camera had a lot of "depth of field", but it still had to be manually focused. And it was the manual focus that "done it in". Mine required pliers, and much hand strength. It was NOT a good design.

@jstola I already had done several pictures changing parameters. I'm going to add more data to my question.
